# How to reimport module variable that's read from a separate file?

Tags: python, ipython, python-import, spyder

I am wondering how to update a module import even when the contents of that module are not *explicitly* changed. I'm working in Spyder. For example, I have a simplified file directory:

```
test/
├── main.py
├── test_data.py
└── test_data.csv
```

I have a data file:

```
# test_data.csv

x,  y
1,  5
3,  20
```

This file is read into a module using pandas and saved as a variable.

```
# test_data.py

from pandas import read_csv
t_data = read_csv("test_data.csv", sep=',')
print(t_data)
```

The `main.py` file then imports this variable from the module and prints it out:

```
# main.py

from test_data import t_data
print(t_data)
```

If I run `main`, then the expected occurs:

```
   x   y
0  1   5
1  3  20

   x   y
0  1   5
1  3  20
```

However, if I subsequently change the contents of the CSV file (e.g. make the second row "2, 10"), then this change is not reflected when `main` is re-evaluated:

```
   x   y
0  1   5
1  3  20
```

It seems that the interpreter doesn't re-evaluate and reimport the module because there were not any *explicit* changes to the module. When I *do* make explicit changes to the module (in addition to the file),

```
# test_data.py

t_data = read_csv("test_data.csv", sep=',')
print('Hello')  # <-- Added this line
print(t_data)
```

then running `main` returns:

```
Hello

   x   y
0  1   5
1  2  10

   x   y
0  1   5
1  2  10
```

I realize that there is probably a better way to do all this, but I'm curious about the behavior here. Is there a way to make the CSV data updated in the module every time it's run?

Comment: Even if there *were* explicit changes to the module, re-importing it would simply return the existing module object, rather than reloading anything from disk.  Instead of importing the data itself, import a function that will load the data; that way you never have to reimport anything, just call the function each time you want a fresh copy of the data.

Comment: This is a good idea, and it's actually exactly what I ended up doing. I've added some more details above to clarify what happens when explicit changes are made to the module.